# Correct iptables configuration for ip forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I think I miss something during configuration. Ping still shows host is not reachable

My goal is to access remote host 10.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.99.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
[image]
After playing with different AllowedIPs I finally get traffic flow as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable IP forwarding on 10.0.0.99

> user@wg-server:~$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf  | grep -i forw
> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
>
> reload sysctls: sudo systemctl reload sysctl

2. Set proper routes on the wireguard clients:
   If `AllowedIPs` directive on .99 and .2 do not include 0.0.0.0/0, or  a network including 10.0.0.0/24 then add:
   `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24` <<<<< include this on your client configuration or extend the current AllowedIPs list.

Comment: 1. ip_forwarding enabled on all servers

2. changed everywhere where possible AllowedIPs to 10.0.0.0/24
but still not luck :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most certainly from the way wireguard's [cryptokey routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) works:

> Cryptokey Routing
>
> At the heart of WireGuard is a concept called Cryptokey Routing, which
> works by **associating public keys with a list of tunnel IP addresses
> that are allowed** inside the tunnel.

this association is declared with `allowed-ips`/`AllowedIPs`. Thus at a given time, on a given wireguard interface, one associated IP address can be associated with *only one* peer. (Probably nothing prevents to use more than one wireguard interface to "overcome" this, but this probably wouldn't scale as well.)

So if each node has this setting:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
```

it's fine for nodes connected to *one* peer and thus declaring this *once*, but becomes wrong for a node with *multiple* peers. A routing node having multiple peers, it's always wrong for it.

On *marat3c* when the first peer's config section, from my guess, 10.0.0.2's peer, is read, 10.0.0.0/24 is associated to this peer. Then when the second peer's (10.0.0.99's) config section is read, 10.0.0.0/24 is *removed* from the first peer and associated to the second peer. If you now type just `wg` on *marat3c*, you 'll get something like this:

```
interface: wg0
[...]

peer: (right peer's public key)
  endpoint: [...]
  allowed ips: (none)

peer: (left peer's public key)
  endpoint: [...]
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/24
```

If you change the order of the configuration you'll just reverse the problem: you can never have both with `allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/24`, the other will switch to `(none)`, as explained at the start.

The multi-peer node should use only the IP addresses (often just one) expected to appear on the given peer to avoid this clash. So on *marat3c*'s wg-quick's config use `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.99` for the left peer, and `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2` for the right peer. You can also correct it "manually" (won't save it) using [`wg`](https://manpages.debian.org/wireguard-tools/wg.8) instead of [`wg-quick`](https://manpages.debian.org/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8) with:

```
wg set wg0 peer 'longpublickeyforleftpeer' allowed-ips 10.0.0.99
wg set wg0 peer 'longpublickeyforrightpeer' allowed-ips 10.0.0.2
```